# android dynamically set width of a view using CountDownTimer

Tags: android

Hi i have a countdown timer and im wanting to add a bar that decreases in width as the countdown timer runs its onTick() method. the bar will need to adjust its width and based on screen size and the countdown timer. I intially pass in a int value that is saved when the timer is paused so for example if points is 100 the bars width is 100% of the screen countdown counts for 10 seconds the points become 80 points so the bar should take up 80% off the screen. Does anyone know how to do this i haven't had much experience dynamically creating views im used to doing it in xml?

heres my timer

```
public void startTimer(){
    try {
     points = Integer.valueOf(data.getString("points"));
     counter = new MyCount(points/2 * 1000,1000);
     counter.start();

    } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void pauseTimer(){

    try {
        counter.cancel();
        data.put("points", String.valueOf(points));
        updateData();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
    public MyCount(long totalTime, long countDownInterval) {
        super(totalTime, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
    pauseTimer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    points = points - 2; 
    //set length of bar based on int value of points
        // Countdown bar to reduce width on countdown
    // if width is less than half way change color of countdown bar to orange
    // if width is less than a 3rd change color to red  

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusting the views width on the fly might be a little tricky since the layout that view belongs to, might also change.

You can write your own view. Just override the `onDraw()` and draw a filled rectangle using `Canvas`. Set your view's width to `match_parent`. And when drawing you can calculate filled width by `getWidth() * percentage /100f`.

By the way wouldn't be easier if you just use a horizontal progress bar?

Comment: how can i acheive the same effect with a progress bar

Comment: Just add `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"` to your layout xml to make the progressbar horizontal. Use `setMax()` and `setProgress()` to adjust the value.